# changing directory with python and os.chdir

Tags: python, cmd

I want to call some program with some keys in the Python script.
Actually, I need to save some files in the other format:

```
os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeProgram\bin")
os.system("mmain.exe "+oldname+" /saveas "+newname+" /exit")
```

Problem is that Python script could be on the other disk (D:/, for example). I've tried:
1)

```
os.system(some cmd-comands like CHDIR \D)
```

2)

```
os.chdir(like in example)
```

3)

```
from subprocess import call
call(["commands"])
```

Every single time I have something wrong. Mostly - I get error "syntax error in the name of directory, file, etc.".
Any advices?
Here is log:

```
m:\unsorted\SocToCor\test>python SocratToCortesExpress.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SocratToCortesExpress.py", line 23, in <module>
os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\SimInTech\bin")
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома(syntax error in the name of file/ directory/ disk): 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SimInTech\x08in'.
```

I don't know why "bin" becomes "x08in"

Comment: can you show the tb? I don't understand your examples at all

Comment: m:\unsorted\SocToCor\test>python SocratToCortesExpress.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocratToCortesExpress.py", line 23, in <module>
    os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\SimInTech\bin")
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или мет
ке тома(syntax error in the name of file/ directory/ disk): 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SimInTech\x08in'. I don't know why "bin" becomes "x08in"

Comment: Please edit it into your question with correct formatting. It's tough to read as a comment.

Comment: You can specify an execution directory when using [subprocess.call(..., cwd="...")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and you should escape the backslashes

Comment: Did you try to print the path? As `\\ ` is a quote character, is needs to be typed twice...

Comment: yep, double slashes. Sorry for the dumb question.